# How to create spinner with heading in it?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, spinner, android-spinner

I am just thinking to create like below in spinner, but i am not sure how to make it work

```
 Fruits (heading unclickable) 
    Apple
    Mango
    Orange
 Cars (heading unclickable)
    BMW
    Lenova
```

Is that possible in Spinner or if you know any other method to create like this, then it would be great.

I am getting those details from the local database. Heading from one table and records from one table.
I am looking for any example or solution.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long time i found a way to do this. I achieved by combining a `Button` and `Expandable ListView`. What i have done is i created a button like spinner. OnClick I launched a popup Activity with Expandable list view in it by calling `startActivityForResult()` which returns the selected value. Finally i replaced the button text with the selected value.

If you looking for Expandable ListView Tutorial you can click below link.

(http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Spinner example in the [Hello Views tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).  They accomplish this by using a TextView for the heading, and the spinner for the selectable list of options.

Comment: I think this is normal spinner with adapter.. i am looking for different one which i specified in the question..